# Qt and SQlite Database, How do i count queries?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I've tried a lot of things.

```
query.isNull()
```

tried the `query.Record()` then `int col = query.Record()`

if I put `query.size()` it will return -1 even if the query has result.

How do i count queries in SQLite?

I wanted to do this:-

```
 if(the query returns null or empty) 
 {
  do this;
 }
  else 
 {
  do that;
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of rows that will be returned without fetching them all? (You can't: the DB engine doesn't know how many there are until it gets to the end. In a complex query, this is enormously helpful.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

query.size() does not work with the SQlite database driver in Qt. You can do:

```
query.exec();
bool gotResults = false;
while (query.next()) {
  gotResults = true;
  // do something with the result using query.value(...)
}
if (!gotResults) {
  // do something else
}
```